# Pandas summation of neighboring rows (rolling sum)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know is there any quick method to sum up the besides row of an dataframe. I can do that with python for loop but it's slow, so I would like to know is there any method to do the same thing while running faster.

Here's a code example of what I'm trying to do.

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {
    'In':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

forecast = 1
temp = []
for i in range(len(df["1"])):
    temp = temp + [sum(df["In"][i - forecast : i + forecast + 1])]

df["Out"] = temp

df["Out"][:forecast] = None
df["Out"][-forecast:] = None

print(df)


#Output:
    In   Out
0    1   NaN
1    2   6.0     #(1+2+3)
2    3   9.0     #(2+3+4)
3    4  12.0      ...
4    5  15.0
5    6  18.0
6    7  21.0
7    8  24.0
8    9  27.0
9   10  30.0
10  11  33.0
11  12  36.0
12  13  39.0
13  14  42.0
14  15   NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rolling` sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html) and set `center=True`

```
df['Out'] = df['In'].rolling(3, center=True).sum()
df

    In   Out
0    1   NaN
1    2   6.0
2    3   9.0
3    4  12.0
4    5  15.0
5    6  18.0
6    7  21.0
7    8  24.0
8    9  27.0
9   10  30.0
10  11  33.0
11  12  36.0
12  13  39.0
13  14  42.0
14  15   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, helps a lot. I will check out the document of df.rolling soon to actually see why is it working.